# Highstock/chart - On resize, don't crop chart

Tags: javascript, viewport, highcharts

**How to keep the chart from cropping on resize, but instead just change its viewport**?

I find it a a bit hard to explain, so please let me know if more explanation is needed.

The chart on the first screenshot look nice, they have a 'normal spacing between them and the bars are not cropped. This one has a 1000px width.

[Chart box wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V3tw.png)

On the second screenshot, the chart is only 300px wide, and the candlesticks become 'cropped'..

[Chart box cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiNvB.png)

Instead I would like to only change the viewport, so that the bars are never cropped and are always te same size.. Only the date-range (Viewport) changes.. You see more bars on a wider chart, but it doesn't meen the bars itself should grow or shrink.

I tried it with simple algoritme, but its very prone to error.

```
    let parentW = this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.clientWidth,
        data = this.chart.xAxis[0].series[0].data,
        barW = 10,
        barsToShow = Math.ceil(parentW / barW),
        firstBar = (data[data.length - barsToShow] || data[0]),
        lastBar = data[data.length - 1];

    this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(firstBar.x, lastBar.x, redraw);
```

I couldn't find any setting in the Highcharts doc and google didn't help much either. Many thanks

Comment: I do not think there is an option for it. However, you can increase [groupPixelWidth](http://jsfiddle.net/b894z8ug/1/) for a smaller chart - it should solve your issue. You can do it with responsive rules if you use Highcharts 5+ or by series.update for Highcharts 5-

Comment: Thanks @morganfree, it does what I need indeed. This is way better then the hacky zoom calculation. Can you make it an answer so I can set it as solution? :)

Comment: Great, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desired behaviour can be achieved with the changing data grouping [groupPixelWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.area.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth) property.

When the chart has smaller width than, e.g. 300px, groupPixelWdith can be set to a higher value.

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            dataGrouping: {
              groupPixelWidth: 30
            }
          }
        }
      },
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 300
      }
    }]
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b894z8ug/1/